# MVC 4 - where to keep business logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement MVC for the first time. I have read many blogs and a pro mvc book too. Now when I am implementing it I cannot figure out where to put some of my business logic

I have Domain Model defined with Linq to SQL. I understand the repository pattern is used to add persistence to model. However I cannot decide where to put the actual business logic. e.g. There is a specific model that needs to be checked for duplicates before it is saved. and also some other logic goes in which decides if this model is qualified to be saved.  Where do you put such logic? Should I put this inside the repository? OR should I plugin a business layer on top of repository.

So it will look like

Controller -> Business Logic -> Repository -> DL

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: create a 3-tier project with logic layer and data layer

Answer (score -1):

If the project is not too large I generally put the business logic into a separate project in the main project.  You can move it to the repository if you have it set up already or you can just pass in the datacontext to the helper to remove redundancy and allow the helper to simply look up some situation and report a true or false response.

If the project is extremely large I will generally move the data to its own project and introduce a data-access layer such as repo or similar to allow the client to get the data without explicit calling of data.

Comment: Thank you for replying - so in essence my controller will be calling business logic?

Controller -> Business Logic -> Repository -> DL ???

Comment: I am not sure the best way to word this but there are many questions on Stack Overflow that talk more about this that you can research where it is probably worded better.  Personally my controllers use business logic to perform some tests but it does not HAVE to go through business logic to get data, in fact I generally pass a data context to the business logic and let the logic perform functions.